# Seperate Dataframe by label (convert dataframe into numpy array)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe and I want to separate the them into different arrays according to their label, I'm not sure on how to filter it by its index. Not sure on how if this is properly being done:

## Example of Dataset (df)

```
Cancer_Type  | Variable | Data Split | Target
Cancer1         43        Train        Good
Cancer5         34        Train        Bad
Cancer2         34        Test         Good
Cancer3         23        Test         Bad
Cancer4         25        Test         Good
```

Possibly doing something like this?

```
#initial split into train/test data
train = df['split'] == 'train'
print("train")
print(train)
test = df['split'] == 'test'
print("valid")
print(test)

X_test = test.values[-1, :-1]
y_test = test.values[-1, -1]

# Get the remaining dataset
X = train.values[:-1, :-1]
y = train.values[:-1, -1]

print("X")
#print(type(X))
#print(X)

print("y")
#print(type(y))
#print(y)

# Split the remaining dataset into train and calibration sets.
X_train, X_cal, y_train, y_cal = train_test_split(X, y)
 
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(X_cal.shape, y_cal.shape)
```

Hopefully by row.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you wish to split the data into train and test sets according to an observation's `Data Split` value. After which, you will again split the train set into train and calibration. The standard data preprocessing methodology involves creating our features, `X` and our target, `y`.

```
# Get dataframes of train and test features
X_train = df[df['Data Split'] == 'Train'].drop(columns = ['Target']).to_numpy()
X_test = df[df['Data Split'] == 'Test'].drop(columns = ['Target']).to_numpy()

# Get arrays of train and test targets
y_train = df[(df['Data Split'] == 'Train')]["Target"].to_numpy()
y_test = df[(df['Data Split'] == 'Test')]["Target"].to_numpy()

# Split the train dataset further into train and validation/calibration sets.
X_train, X_cal, y_train, y_cal = train_test_split(X_train, y_train)
```

You now have your train, validation/calibration and test sets in array form.

If you wish to preserve the `Target` variable, simply

```
train = df[df['Data Split'] == 'Train'].to_numpy()
test = df[df['Data Split'] == 'Test'].to_numpy()
```

Comment: (nice user name btw) this is exactly the idea.  1. Seperate the test set from the whole dataset 2. Then using the remaining dataset, split it into train and calibrate data.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error with the first line of code, `X_test = df[df['split'] == 'valid'].drop(columns = ['output'].to_numpy()`

Comment: @bioinformatics_student I missed out a closing bracket when specifying which column to drop. Kindly check the updated code.
```X_test = df[df['split'] == 'valid'].drop(columns = ['output']).to_numpy()```

Comment: thanks for the update, not giving issues now :) I wanted to know if it would be possible to manually split the data into training and test data (in second step) without using the scikit helper?

Comment: @MrDoLoSoLo sorry for my ignorance on this, I'm still getting familiar with this whole topic of ML.

Comment: @bioinformatics_student No worries. You can definitely do that by that is not advised. sklearn's `train_test_split` is much simpler to implement. It automatically shuffles the data and you can even specify additional parameters like stratify. If you insist,

`# Shuffle the data.
df = df.sample(frac=1)

# Specify your test size.
test_size = int(0.2 * len(df))

#Split the original train dataset.
train = df[test_size:]
test = df[:test_size]`

Comment: Thanks, mostly out of curiosity and hopefully apply to other functions. I have hopefully one last question, I run into this error when trying to fit my model to the training data: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'` and `ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas Da                                                                                        taFrames` is this because of the scikit function being used?

Comment: @bioinformatics_student Oops, I mistook `X_train` for a dataframe instead of an array. To shuffle an array, simply use `np.random.shuffle(X_train)`. The other two steps remain the same.

Comment: Do I need to apply this to only X_train? Because I still get the error after applying this :s

Comment: Your goal is to split the train data, both features and target, further into train and calibration sets. It would help to provide the error and the model you are trying to fit.